# Grails Quartz dynamic scheduling Import issue

Tags: grails, quartz-scheduler, grails-plugin, jobs

I want to use dynamic scheduling feature of Grails quartz plugin.

I am running `grails 2.3.5` and the quartz plugin (`quartz:1.0.2`).

I am able to persist the quartz information to my mysql database and I am able to run normal quartz Jobs.

The problem is scheduling tasks dynamically. I am not getting this to work.

Here is my setup and what I am trying to do:

I have a simple Job in `"grails-app/tao/marketing/MarketingJob"` which looks like this:

```
package tao.marketing
import org.quartz.JobExecutionContext; 
import org.quartz.JobExecutionException; 

class MarketingJob {

static triggers ={}

def execute(JobExecutionContext context) {
     try{
        def today = new Date()
        println today
    }
    catch (Throwable e) {
       throw new JobExecutionException(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
  }
}
```

Which I now try to schedule dynamically from a Service.

```
package tao

import grails.transaction.Transactional
import tao.marketing.CampaignSchedule
import tao.Person
import jobs.tao.marketing.*



class ScheduleService {

def scheduleMarketingForPerson(CampaignSchedule campaignSchedule, Person person) {
    log.info("Schedule new Marketing for: "+person.last_name)
        campaignSchedule.scheduleActions.each {
            Date today = new Date();
            Date scheduleDate = today+it.afterXdays
            log.info("ScheduleAction: "+it.id+": "+scheduleDate)
            MarketingJob.schedule(scheduleDate, ["scheduleActions.id":it.id,     "person.apiKey":person.apiKey])
        }
    }
}
```

In my IDE (STS) `MarketingJob` cannot be found.

```
 MarketingJob.schedule(scheduleDate, ["scheduleActions.id":it.id,     "person.apiKey":person.apiKey])
```

How do I correctly import the Marking Job? 
Do I understand the dynamic scheduling feature correctly?

Comment: I have just tested my code from a Controller. There it works without any issues. The question is really why can't I access MarketingJob (grails-app/jobs/..) from within a grails Service. What does the trick?

Comment: You have job in `grails-app/tao/marketing/MarketingJob`? Shouldn't it be in `grails-app/jobs/tao/marketing/MarketingJob`?

Answer (score 0):

Could be that your job is in "package tao.marketing" and your import is "import jobs.tao.marketing.*"? I mean, import starts with "jobs"

Answer (score 0):

The problem I had was that in my STS IDE I didn't have the jobs directory marked as a code directory. Thanks for all your comments.